# ¿Como desembarazarse de NaN en python SFrame?

Tags: python

Quiero deshacerme de lineas de una dataframe que tengan `NaN` pero cuando hago `item_info.dropna(axis = 0, how='all')`,
que proviene de la documentación de [pandas.pydata.org](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), no funciona bien:

```
item_info.dropna(axis = 0, how='all')
```

Usando esto con

```
m2 = ranking_factorization_recommender.create(subcriber_eclipse,
                                              target='count',
                                              user_data = subcriber_eclipse,
                                              item_data = sf_test)
```

Da el siguiente error:

> ```
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>
> <ipython-input-44-02025aac0088> in <module>()
> ----> 1 item_info.dropna(axis = 0, how='all')
>       2 
>       3 #item_info.fillna(0, inplace=True)
>       4 
>       5 #print item_info
>
> TypeError: dropna() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'
> ```

la tabla proviene de una consulta SQL :

```
item_info = graphlab.SFrame.from_sql(conn,"""--- matrice d'utilisation des hastags par les eclipses
SELECT COUNT (eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id), eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id FROM eclipse_hashtag
    GROUP BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id, eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id
      ORDER BY eclipse_hashtag.hashtag_id,eclipse_hashtag.eclipse_id ASC;
    """)

item_info.rename({'eclipse_id':'item_id'})
```

Aqui está la estructura :

```
type(item_info)

graphlab.data_structures.sframe.SFrame
```

Y aqui esta  la traza del error al completo

> ```
> [ERROR] graphlab.toolkits._main: Toolkit error: Missing value (None) encountered in column 'item_id.1'. Use the SFrame's dropna
> function to drop rows with 'None' values in them.`
>
> ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
> ToolkitError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-8-56b88cdef560> in <module>()
>       9 m2 = ranking_factorization_recommender.create(subcriber_eclipse,
> target='count',
>      10                                               user_data = subcriber_eclipse,
> ---> 11                                               item_data = item_info)
>      12 
>
> /home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/toolkits/recommender/ranking_factorization_recommender.pyc
> in create(observation_data, user_id, item_id, target, user_data,
> item_data, num_factors, regularization, linear_regularization,
> side_data_factorization, ranking_regularization,
> unobserved_rating_value, num_sampled_negative_examples,
> max_iterations, sgd_step_size, random_seed, binary_target, solver,
> verbose, **kwargs)
>     267         opts.update(kwargs)
>     268 
> --> 269     response = _graphlab.toolkits._main.run('recsys_train', opts, verbose)
>     270 
>     271     return RankingFactorizationRecommender(response['model'])
>
> /home/antoine/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/graphlab/toolkits/_main.pyc
> in run(toolkit_name, options, verbose, show_progress)
>      87         _get_metric_tracker().track(metric_name, value=1, properties=track_props, send_sys_info=False)
>      88 
> ---> 89         raise ToolkitError(str(message))
>
> ToolkitError: Missing value (None) encountered in column 'item_id.1'. Use the SFrame's dropna function to drop rows with 'None'
> values in them.
> ```

Comment: Marine es muy extraño eso, con ese código debes conseguir eliminar todas las filas en las que  todos sus elementos son NaN. Lo uso a menudo, pero ante la duda lo he testeado en Pandas 0.20.1, he actualizado a la 0.20.2 (por si fuera un bug en la subversión) y no hay manera de reproducir tu problema ni en Python 2.7 ni en Python 3.6.. Algo más se nos escapa. Prueba a reproducir alguno de los ejemplos que dan en la documentación en un nuevo Notebook a ver si te pasa lo mismo.

Comment: Marine dada tu pregunta anterior y sabiendo que usas **SFrame**, mira a ver si por alguna casualidad `item_info` no fuera un `pandas.DataFrame` sino un `graphlab.SFrame`. Lo digo porque SFrame tiene el mismo método pero sus argumentos son `SFrame.dropna(columns=None, how='any')`, lo cual explicaría el error. Seria bueno que aportaras la traza del error al completo o verifica el tipo de tu objeto con `type(item_info)`. Saludos.

Comment: Si eso es, esta una **SFrame** !

Comment: @FJSevilla añadí  la traza del error al completo y voy a eproducir alguno de los ejemplos que dan en la documentación en un nuevo Notebook. Muchas gracias por toda su ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

He modificado un poco la pregunta ya que no estás usando [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) DataFrames.

Debido a que no usas [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) no deberías usar su documentación. La documentación de los SFrames indica que `axis` no es una keyword válida pero sí puedes usar `columns`. Leyendo [su documentación](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.dropna.html#graphlab.SFrame.dropna) deberías poder hacer lo que quieres de la siguiente forma:

```
item_info.dropna(columns=None, how='all')
```

Comment: Me da el mismo error : `ToolkitError: Missing value (None) encountered in column 'item_id.1'. Use the SFrame's dropna function to drop rows with 'None' values in them.`

Comment: Supuestamente maneja `NaN`s y `None`s. Si pegas la fila de datos que te da error igual se puede mirar un poco más pero sin más información es difícil ayudarte. Otra opción que se me ocurre es que `item_info` esté vacio y no haya filas para aplicar el `dropna`. ¿Has testeado que la *query* realmente te devuelve valores?

Answer (score 0):

Parece que el error no lo lanza `dropna` sino que alguno de los métodos que usas no admite que existan columnas con algún valor nulo.

Partiendo de un ejemplo:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> sf = graphlab.SFrame({'a': [1, None, np.nan],
                          'b': [3, None,   None],
                          'c': [4,    5, np.nan], 
                          'd': [6,    7,      8]})
>>> sf
Data:
+------+------+-----+---+
|  a   |  b   |  c  | d |
+------+------+-----+---+
| 1.0  |  3   | 4.0 | 6 |
| None | None | 5.0 | 7 |
| nan  | None | nan | 8 |
+------+------+-----+---+
```

`dropna` **elimina la fila o filas completas** dependiendo del parámetro `how`:

- **`how = 'all'`**: elimina solo la fila si tiene `todos los valores nulos` en todas las columnas especificadas en `columns`:

  ```
  >>> sf.dropna(columns=None, how='all')   
  Data:
  +------+------+-----+---+
  |  a   |  b   |  c  | d |
  +------+------+-----+---+
  | 1.0  |  3   | 4.0 | 6 |
  | None | None | 5.0 | 7 |
  | nan  | None | nan | 8 |
  +------+------+-----+---+

  >>> sf.dropna(columns=['a', 'b'], how='all')
  Data:
  +-----+---+-----+---+
  |  a  | b |  c  | d |
  +-----+---+-----+---+
  | 1.0 | 3 | 4.0 | 6 |
  +-----+---+-----+---+
  ```
- **`how = 'any'`**: elimina una fila si existe `al menos un valor nulo` en algunas de las columnas especificadas en `columns`.

  ```
  >>> sf.dropna(columns=None, how='any')
  Data:
  +-----+---+-----+---+
  |  a  | b |  c  | d |
  +-----+---+-----+---+
  | 1.0 | 3 | 4.0 | 6 |
  +-----+---+-----+---+


  >>> sf.dropna(columns=['c', 'd'], how='any')
  Data:
  +------+------+-----+---+
  |  a   |  b   |  c  | d |
  +------+------+-----+---+
  | 1.0  |  3   | 4.0 | 6 |
  | None | None | 5.0 | 7 |
  +------+------+-----+---+
  ```

Como ves funciona tanto con `None` como con valores `nan` reales. Si aplicas `sf.dropna(columns=None, how='all')` eliminaras solo las filas con todos sus valores nulos pero no cosas como `[None, None, 5.0, 7]`. Ten también cuidado con valores nulos no reconocidos como tales como `'NaN'` sobre todo si lees datos de un csv.

Si alguna de las funciones que tienes no admite que existan valores nulos en el SFrame o bién eliminas toda fila que qenga al menos un valor nulo `how='any'` o usas fillna para pasar esos valores nulos a 0 por ejemplo.

Esto depende de tus datos, de su naturaleza y de cómo y qué estes evaluando. Puede que eliminar una fila con un solo valor nulo sea perder datos y esto no es asumible. En el caso de pasar los valores nulos a 0 es lo mismo, hay casos en los que None puede ser equivalente a 0 y casos en los que esto no es cierto. Debes evaluar esto y actuar en consecuencias, si es que el problema es el que expongo.

[`Sframe.fillna`](https://turi.com/products/create/docs/generated/graphlab.SFrame.fillna.html) tiene como argumentos la columna sobre la que aplicar la operación y el valor por el que sustituir los nulos:

```
>>> sf.fillna(column='a', value=0.0)
Data:
+-----+------+-----+---+
|  a  |  b   |  c  | d |
+-----+------+-----+---+
| 1.0 |  3   | 4.0 | 6 |
| 0.0 | None | 5.0 | 7 |
| 0.0 | None | nan | 8 |
+-----+------+-----+---+
```

Comment: Tengo una cosa  bastante peculiar : he  hecho `print "item_info : ",item_info.print_rows(2240,3)` para ver todas las valores y nunca hay `NaN` o `None` ...

Comment: @Marine1 lo único que se me ocurre si eso es así, es que en algún momento intermedio entre la aplicación de `dropna` y la función que retorna el error se genere un Sframe que si tenga valores `None`. Debes intentar aislar la función o método que lanza el error y ir hacia atrás para ver si en algún momento se genera un SFrame que si tenga valores nulos como resultado del procesamiento de tu SFrame original. Saludos.

Comment: Si, tienes razón. A mi parecer esta es cuando utiliso `ranking_factorization_recommender.create` (que he añadido en la pregunta). Tal vez esta la relacion entre las tres tablas que crea `NaN` o `Null` en ella misma.